# How to solve the error "Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame"

Tags: r

```
abc4 <- lm(Sales~., data=abc4)
summary(abc4)

abc5 <- lm(Sales~ T+June+July+August+September+October+November+December, data=abc4)
summary(abc5)
```

I'm trying to run regression. If I run the first regression (abc4), it works just fine. But if I do the second regression, it shows an error saying below.

> Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :    cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’
> to a data.frame

I don't get why it works the first time but doesn't the second time.

My data consists of variables including Sales and 11 dummy variables (Feb~Dec) and Time period (1-60)

Comment: Is your `abc4 <- lm(Sales~., data=abc4) summary(abc4)` overwriting your `abc4` dataframe called in the `abc5` line?

Comment: I'm very new to R so I'm not certain. But after reading your comment, I tried the regression with another random name as below.
regression <- lm(Sales~., data=abc4), but it still not working and the same error message is showing up. I'm not sure why it's working the first time and now working the second time once I make any changes.

Comment: Do a `str(abc4)` to see if the object is a list or a dataframe.  If you overwrote the dataframe `abc4` you will probably have to recreate it.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in partiucular provide a complete example including input showing it using dput to make it reproducible.  As @SteveM has already pointed out the first line overwrites abc4 so when you get to the second lm it has the wrong value.  If you are getting errors even after fixing that then they are related to items not shown in the question so no one can help you with that.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked, thanks so much! @SteveM

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting data abc4 with the `lm()` object. You can do this by running the following:

```
abc4.out <- lm(Sales~., data=abc4)

summary(abc4.out)

abc5.out <- lm(Sales~ T+June+July+August+September+October+November+December, data=abc4)

summary(abc5.out)
```